# Manage UniFi DHCP reservations on UDM via shell

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp, dhcpd, ubiquiti, unifi

I'd like to be able to manage DHCP reservations on my Ubiquiti Dream Machine (UDM) directly via shell (scripting or Ansible would also be acceptable). I've tried to locate dhcpd or dnsmasq configuration files that can be edited and persist through reboots or upgrades but am coming up blank. Is this possible on Unifi OS (3.x)? Are the service and config actually inside the unifi container?

Comment: I would like to bump this question. I have about 120 static reservations that I would like to be able to edit via a single file if possible.